# the unity of intent-filter Android manifest file

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, manifest

manifest was overlap when you implement in-app with AdMob to unity can be implemented by each haryeoneunde but combine the two into one. So the text in the [intent-filter] to modify the manifest file of the duplicate traits . Be duplicated write them off against each other , the icon of the app is produced both in-app only one and the other is a phenomenon that occurred only AdMob .

AdMob had to import the package by using the plug-in , in-app is implemented by sending a jar file in Android.

```
<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity"
     android:label="@string/app_name" 
     android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" >
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
     <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
</activity>

<activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
     android:name="com.company.testproject.MainActivity" >
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I could not able to resolve this problem . Please help ^^

Comment: you are a manifest?!

Comment: AdMob had to import the package by using the plug-in , in-app is implemented by sending a jar file in Android.

Comment: Most questions here are answered in just a few moments, I think the reason why your questioned is not answered yet is the bad syntax you used. For more clarity please edit your question. I can't even understand what the problem is.